# Does Exoplayer2 always cause onSurfaceSizeChanged() to be called at least twice?

Tags: android-layout, exoplayer2.x

My app utilizes a custom FrameLayout that contains a PlayerView and another custom FrameLayout ("DrawView"). The goal is to draw customized shapes on the FrameLayout that appear on top of the video being played.

In the layout, I have PlayerView first, then the DrawView:

```
<!-- customized FrameLayout encompassing ViewPager2 and DrawView, which implements that capability of
         detecting taps -->
<com.reddragon.intouch.utils.ViewPager2Host
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager2host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".ui.MediaPlayerActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/activity_media_player_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

    <com.reddragon.intouch.ui.drawview.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/drawView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The `DrawView` component is used to draw shapes and text over the top of the video, and so I need to resize it to match the size and position of the rect that represents where the video is played.

I have the logic correctly implemented to do this, and I have implemented VideoListener and placed this logic within `onSurfaceSizeChanged()`.

This works fine - and as you can see from the screenshot, the red line (representing the bounds of the enclosing parent ViewPager2Host) and the green line (representing the bounds/placement of the video surface view I calculated at runtime for this particular video) is correct:

[image]

Here is my question - `onSurfaceSizeChanged()` gets called multiple times, and I only want to do the calculation of size and location once for `DrawView`. From my testing it appears that as long as the `ViewPager2Host` parent does not change dimensions, then `onSurfaceSizeChanged()` gets called twice, and the second time is the "final" dimension.

Can anyone confirm that this is the case? Or are there cases - perhaps where the parent dimensions exactly match the video surface view dimension that `onSurfaceSizeChanged()` would only be called once?

Or is there some way to know when the surface size is 'final'?

I'm trying to implement some sort of 'if video is initializing then' logic so that only AFTER all layout is complete and the video surface rect has been finalized, do I calculate the size and placement of DrawView.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to my original question appears to be: NO - there is no guarantee on how many times this gets called in the normal rendering pipeline, except that it is called at least once.

Upon further testing, it also becomes clear that even after onPlayerStateChanged() gets called with STATE_READY, the video size is not yet stable (I've seen numerous times now that onSurfaceSizeChanged() gets called with updated values even after STATE_READY gets called).

So my original idea of handling everything in onPlayerStateChanged() after playWhenReady is TRUE does not now seem to be a good answer.

Still looking for how I can tell the video surface has settled down to the size it thinks is "final" for playing the video!

As a refresher, my customized FrameLayout has three "layers" (each of which completely fill the holder associated with the current ViewPager2 adapter):

1. Media display (either a Glide implementation for images, or ExoPlayer2 PlayerView for Media)
2. DrawView (customized FrameLayout which holds the various shapes drawn on top)
3. FrameLayout (holding an indeterminant progress bar and text shown when video media from the Internet is taking a while to buffer)

My solution ended up being (upon the "next" item in the ViewPager2 recyclerview being ready to display a video):

1. Initially hide the DrawView and Media Display layers
2. Show the "loading" components
3. setPlayerWhenReady(true) on the ExoPlayer
4. prepare(mediaDataSource)
5. Within the onPlayerStateChanged() callback from ExoPlayer that my activity implements, test for both playWhenReady being TRUE and the plabackState being STATE_READY, and then
6. remove the "loading" views
7. set the ExoPlayer view visible
8. calculate the various drawing widgets within DrawView given the ExoPlayer's videoSurfaceView dimensions and position
9. set the DrawView Visible.

I'm not sure why, but it seems overriding other callbacks like those from VideoListener didn't "jog" the views to draw themselves properly. I saw numerous cases where onDraw() of the DrawView class would be called, but neither onDraw of the widgets, or onDispatchDraw of the DrawView class would be called.